# Unable to use enum field in query in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm developing some kind of CMS where I have a hierarchy of different content types.

The base content class is:

```
[Table("Content")]
public abstract class CmsContent {
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public abstract CmsContentType Type { get; }
    public CmsContentLocation Location { get; set; }

    public CmsContent()
    { }
}
```

The `CmsContentType` is enum:

```
public enum CmsContentType: byte {
    None = 0,
    Text = 1,
    News = 2,
    Document = 3,
    Link = 4,
    Image = 5,
    Banner = 6
}
```

A bunch of concrete content types are inherited from `CmsContent` like `TextContent`, `ImageContent` etc.

```
public class TextContent: CmsContent {

    public override CmsContentType Type {
        get { return CmsContentType.Text; }
    }

    public TextContent()
    { }
}
```

All these data is stored in a single table.

The Entity Framework context is (simplified):

```
public class EFDbContext: DbContext {

    public DbSet<CmsContent> Content { get; set; }

    public EFDbContext() { }

    public EFDbContext(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString) { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder mb) {
        mb.Entity<CmsContent>()
            .Map<TextContent>(m => m.Requires("Type").HasValue(1))
            .Map<NewsContent>(m => m.Requires("Type").HasValue(2))
            .Map<DocumentContent>(m => m.Requires("Type").HasValue(3))
            .Map<LinkContent>(m => m.Requires("Type").HasValue(4))
            .Map<ImageContent>(m => m.Requires("Type").HasValue(5))
            .Map<BannerContent>(m => m.Requires("Type").HasValue(6));
    }
}
```

The problem is when I try to select by 'Type' field I got the error.

My repository with query:

```
public class EFCmsContentRepository: EFRepository<CmsContent>, ICmsContentRepository {

    protected override DbSet<CmsContent> Table {
        get { return Context.Content; }
    }

    public CmsContent Find(CmsContentType type) {
        return Table.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == type);
    }
}
```

Error message I got:

> The specified type member 'Type' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

I'm using EF 5 where enum queries are supported, and I have another repository where I successfully select by enum field.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem isn't with `enum`; you'd have the same problem if you change it to use `int`. It's the lack of a property setter, and your attempt to manage the property behind EF's back, that causes the exception. (I'm posting this as a comment instead of an answer because merely knowing what's wrong isn't enough to know how to change your code, and I'm not sure what the most appropriate method would be here.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, to solve the problem I removed `Type` field from each model. 
As **hvd** said we shouldn't manage the properties behind EF's back. Moreover, db table fields used for hierarchy mapping (`Type` in my case) should not be defined in model.
To know the type of content we can use Reflection (however it's rarely needed having good architecture).

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a specific answer to your question however I found this question when looking for the same error message.

My issue was the following definition for an enum which was mapped to a column

```
public enum MyEnum: uint
{
    NOT_SET,
    UNKNOWN,
    BLAH
}
```

EF does not support uint and hence threw the same error

The specified type member 'MyEnum' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only
initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Changing the column to int resolved the issues.